# Yarn How to Specify Install Path for a Package

Tags: yarnpkg

I migrated from bower away and now my dev dependencies are in `node_modules/` while my prod dependencies are in `node_modules/@bower_components/`. This is good because I can easily grab all the front end dependencies in gulp with `node_modules/@bower_components/**/*`. Now I want to install new "bower" packages and I also want them appear in `node_modules/@bower_components/` but they are installed into `node_modules/`. I tried to use `yarn add <package> --modules-folder node_modules/@bower_components` but this moves all my packages into the subfolder.

Comment: Hi Andi ,did you find the solution? I also have the same question.

Comment: When I move all my bower component using bower away method after i remove bower.json and bowerrc file I am unable to serve the project Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\dev\test\MPUI\bower.json' and I have no clue where in my build script it is trying to read that, I tried to search for bower.json n my build script and could not found it, in case you face the same issue and resolve could you share how to fix it

Comment: I didn't find a decent solution for me. There are some solutions mentioned here: https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/4773